# SQL Wrong results during JOIN using alias

Tags: sql, postgresql

During use of `PostgresSQL` I have faced with an issue that if I use the following `JOIN` statement:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
    "AudioRecord"."MergeId",
    "AudioRecord"."DeviceId",
    "AudioRecord"."StartTime",
    "AudioRecord"."EndTime",
    "Description"."Network",
    "Description"."Comment"
FROM
    "Description" 
JOIN 
    "AudioRecord" ON "AudioRecord"."MergeId" = "Description"."MergeId"
```

It produces the proper results.

But if I use the following `JOIN` statement:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
    "AudioRecord"."MergeId",
    "AudioRecord"."DeviceId",
    "AudioRecord"."StartTime",
    "AudioRecord"."EndTime",
    "Description"."Network",
    "Description"."Comment"
FROM
    "Description",
    "Description" AS "Alias0" 
JOIN 
    "AudioRecord" ON "AudioRecord"."MergeId" = "Alias0"."MergeId"
```

By some reason it produces wrong results, `"Description"."Network"` and `"Description"."Comment"` with for example `"Description"."MergeId" = 15` appears in selected row for `"AudioRecord"."MergeId" = 28` ...

What am I doing wrong ?

Alias I need because I have multi-`JOIN` for different table with `"AudioRecord"` table, and without alias it is wrong SQL Query, but with alias it produces wrong results even for `JOIN` for single table

The reason I am experimenting with this, because I have a multi-`JOIN` statement:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
    "AudioRecord"."MergeId",
    "AudioRecord"."DeviceId",
    "AudioRecord"."StartTime",
    "AudioRecord"."EndTime",
    "Description"."Network",
    "Description"."Comment",
    "User"."Name",
    "Location"."Address"
FROM
    "AudioRecord",
    "AudioRecord" AS "Alias0" 
JOIN 
    "Description" ON "Description"."MergeId" = "Alias0"."MergeId",
    "AudioRecord" AS "Alias1" 
JOIN 
    "User" ON "User"."MergeId" = "Alias1"."MergeId",
    "AudioRecord" AS "Alias2" 
JOIN 
    "Location" ON "Location"."MergeId" = "Alias2"."MergeId"
```

And this SQL query merge that same way as with single `JOIN` with alias ...

I want somehow to work it properly

Comment: Sample data and the desired result would help. Any of the above queries answers a question of a kind. What is the question you want your query to answer to exactly?

Comment: @Serg I want to JOIN multiple table with one table like in last SQL query

Comment: All your queries return a single dataset. What are the requirements? For example you want a row in the result for every AudioRecord row plus decoded user, addr etc info from other tables, or what?

Comment: You should read: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins),  because you (still) use those old-style JOINs

Comment: A [mre] of this problem can be seen in this [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/_ie4B45Q)

Comment: Add the table definitions as update to the question.